# SSRS export to Excel results in #####

Tags: excel, reporting-services

When I export a report from SSRS to Excel some columns are formatted as #####. When I export from the ReportServer in Internet Explorer it also gives me these results.

It is not the width of the column in Excel. The fields are numberfields or percentagefields. When I double-click on the cell in Excel the result will be shown. But I have to double-click on all the fields to show the results.

I've also tried to change the format of the column in SSRS, but I cannot find a setting that results in an Excelfile without the ######.

Comment: It is the width of the column.

Comment: In SSRS or Excel? The columns are really width, and the result is 0,00% so I think it is width enough.

Comment: You say it is NOT the width of the column, but does increasing the width do anything? it should. even 0% entered in a cell, (tested) can show as #### if the cell is not wide enough

Comment: And that is exactly my problem. Even if the column is as wide as my screen, it still shows #######. It is because of the export from SSRS. So increasing the width doesn't work.

Comment: Have you changed the format of the cell to percentage format?  In 2005 got to tab artifact the cell right mouse click select properties got format tab.  find format code box click button 2 to the right, can use predetermine formats or roll your own

Comment: can you determine anything bout the existing format?
     MsgBox (ActiveCell.NumberFormat)  would be interested to see a sample of a file to play with

Comment: This is the format: 0.00%
I have two columns with the percentage. In SSRS the both look okay, but after the export to Excel one works and one does not.

Comment: And it only happens when the result is 0,00%